# Neo4j: Combine two databases

Tags: database, neo4j, merge, cypher, graph-databases

I have two databases within one project in Neo4j, one much smaller than the other, and I want to bring the small one into the big one. Some nodes are common to both, but they differ on certain properties.

For instance, it might be the following:

`Database A: (:country{name:'United Kingdom',acronym:'UK'})
Database B: (:country{name:'United Kingdom',acronym:'U.K.'})<-[:lives_in]-(:person{name:'John Smith})`

As you can see, Database A lacks the node 'John Smith'. I would want to bring Database B into Database A, matching on 'name', such that Database A now looks like:

`Database A: (:country{name:'United Kingdom',acronym:'UK'})<-[:lives_in]-(:person{name:'John Smith})`

How would I go about combining the two databases in this way?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To achive what you want to do you need to :

- export the data of database B as CSV files. For this you can use `apoc.export.csv.query` procedure in APOC.
- import in database A the CSV files that you have generated by using the `LOAD CSV` feature of Cypher with some `MERGE` command.

Cheers